# "the very discussed Steven Avery case"

Tags: articles

> I have another question concerning now **the** very discussed Steven Avery case.

Do you find this sentence OK? I am not sure of the potential usage of the article and *apostrophe s* in the name Avery.

Comment: Idiomatic.  The name of the case is not in the possessive. Cf. the Dreyfus affair. But "the much discussed" would be more common than "the very discussed".

Comment: @TRomano - I wonder if we can say "Steven Avery's case" in the sence "his court case, the case under which he was accused". Or maybe "John Doe's case" always means something else: John Doe's set of arguments in favor or against something, or John Doe's responsibility to judge someone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no link/reference/research about the sentence and Google search on the sentence produces nothing but this question.

Comment: @CowperKettle:  both forms are possible (the Avery case, Avery's case) but they have different meanings.  With **the Avery case** the reference is to the case *so named/identified*; with "Avery's case" the reference is to *his* case, the case  involving Avery the person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have another question concerning now the very discussed Steven Avery case. (ungrammatical)

The use of the definite article here is perfectly grammatical, because people understand which unique case the speaker is talking about. However, there is a problem with the word *very* here. The word *very* is an unusual adverb—we can't use it to modify verbs. We only normally use it with adjectives and adverbs. The word *discussed* is a participle form of the verb *DISCUSS*  being used to premodify *Steven Avery case*. When we want to modify verbs like this we usually use the adverb *much* instead:

- *I have another question concerning now the much discussed Steven Avery case.

There is one last problem, which is that it isn't clear exactly what the preposition *now* is referring to in the example above. If it is mean to modify *much discussed* then it need to go directly before this verb phrase:

- I have another question concerning the now much discussed Steven Avery case.

Comment: Hi, Araucaria, the problem of the sentence is not limited to "now". There are more problems.

Comment: @rathony What are the other problems old bean?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to say or write this sentence as

> I have another question concerning,  now,  the very (much) discussed Steven Avery case.

The parenthetical *now* sets apart  this question about the Steve Avery case from prior questions that were about another subject. It's placement in the sentence may not be the most graceful  but when we speak without a script, we might produce such a sentence.

Another example:

> Let's turn,  now, to another question.

And, yes, we don't usually use *very* to directly modify a verb; we use it before another modifier  such as in *the very heavily discussed Steven Avery case*.

Note *the Steven Avery case* is the case whose "feature attraction", so to speak, is Steven Avery, so that his name  becomes the "title" of the case. While *Stephen Avery's case* (NB no definite article) is the case Steven Avery has, or *the case of Steven Avery*.